# Server Response Time and Domain Name Resolution

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, website

I have a server running windows 2003 and apache. I have couple of sites hosted on this box. Now this server is placed at my home and the ISP has allocated me a fixed IP.

When i check for my website's speed in ySlow, in the net panel i can see my domain name resolution takes between 150-350 ms! and for other resources such as a css file of few kbs, it takes good 200-300 ms.

is there a way to improve these timings? i have set up expiry headers and cache on apache. But that does not seem to help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your DNS server as well or is this handled somewhere else?

Comment: i use a free DNS service named DNSEver.

Answer (score 1):

Successive queries for the same DNS resource record (*RR*) should not incur a new external query; typically, DNS response data is cached by the *resolver* (the DNS client) for the duration (the *TTL*) given in the RRs.

If your client does force a full DNS lookup for every request, you may want to investigate that...

NOTE that none of this has anything to do with apache.

Comment: i guess dns response data would be cached. is there a way to check that?

Comment: I would first check the documentation for yslow to see what those numbers really mean.